# Get PARTITION_ID in Dask for Data Frame

Tags: pandas, dataframe, dask, dask-delayed, dask-dataframe

Is it possible to get the `partition_id` in `dask` after splitting `pandas DFs`

For example:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,2), columns=["A","B"])
df_parts = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=2)
part1 = df_parts.get_partition(0)
```

In the 2 parts, `part1` is the `first_partition`. So is it possible to do something like the following:

```
part1.get_partition_id() => which will return 0 or 1
```

Or is it possible to `get the partition ID` by iterating through `df_parts`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about built-in functions, but you can achieve what you want with `enumerate(df_parts.to_delayed())`.

`to_delayed` will produce a list of delayed objects, one per partition, so you can iterate over them, keeping track of the sequential number with `enumerate`.